# My javascript function is not working, when i click to submit my form

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

My javascript function is not working, when i click to submit my form.
can someone help with that? i think is everything all right, but it's not working for some reason i don't know.

```
                        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>my_data" onsubmit="onSubmit()" method ="POST">
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Nome</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name= "changed_user_name" value = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('nome_usuario');?>"></input>
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Email</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "changed_user_email" value = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('email_usuario');?>"></input>
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Digite sua nova senha</p>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "changed_password"></input>
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Confirme sua nova senha</p>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "change_confirm_password"></input>
                        <button id ="btn_mydata_submit_incident" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmit(){
        alert("email inválido");
        var result =1;
        var checar = document.querySelector("#changed_user_email");
        var test = checar.value.indexOf("@");
        if (test == -1){
            alert("email inválido");
            result =0;
        }
        var checar = document.querySelector("#changed_password");
        var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;
        if(!checar.value.match(passw)){
            alert("password inválido");
            result =0;
        }
        if (result ==0){
            return (false);
        }
        else{
            return (true);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: U have JS error !! function onSubmit() needs { for definition !!

Comment: You also don't need "return" from "return onSubmit()" in your form tag.  That is delete the word return here. Should be "onsubmit="onSubmit()"

Comment: Sorry, i deleted the '{' when i formatted the code, is there now ehhe, this is not the problem.

Comment: I deleted the "return" word in the form tag but it still don't work.

Comment: you have used `onclick` event .. **form doesnt have any onclick event** put `onsubmit` ....

Comment: I changed the name of the function onSubmit() and now the script is working, i don't know why it happened. 
Doesnt' make any sense but is working! that's all =D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>my_data" onsubmit="return onSubmit()" method ="POST">
                            <p class = "my_data_text">Nome</p>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name= "changed_user_name" value = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('nome_usuario');?>"></input>
                            <p class = "my_data_text">Email</p>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "changed_user_email" id="changed_user_email" value = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('email_usuario');?>"></input>
                            <p class = "my_data_text">Digite sua nova senha</p>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "changed_password" id="changed_password"></input>
                            <p class = "my_data_text">Confirme sua nova senha</p>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "change_confirm_password"></input>
                            <button id ="btn_mydata_submit_incident" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmit(){

    var result =1;
    var checar = document.getElementById("changed_user_email");
    var test = checar.value.indexOf("@");
    if (test == -1){
        alert("email inválido");
        result =0;
    }

    var checar = document.getElementById("changed_password");
    var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;
    if(!checar.value.match(passw)){
        alert("password inválido");
        result =0;
    }

    if (result ==0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i tried but it's not entering the javascript function

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you're not using the `input type="submit"` but using `button type="submit"`.

You should replace the submit button for this:

```
<input type="submit" value="salvar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_mydata_submit_incident"/>
```

Or just change the `onSubmit` javascript event for the `onclick` one.

Comment: This is not true.  You can submit a form with <button type=submit.  That is valid.

Comment: It is valid but no recommended, it behaves incorrectly many times.

Answer (score 0):

another way you can try doing is

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){ 
 onSubmit(); //call the function,return something true false value from function return and depending on that submit the form

 $('#form_id').submit();

});
```

I hope,it helps you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.. Working for me perfectly...

`<form action="" onsubmit="onSubmit()" method ="POST">
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Nome</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name= "changed_user_name" value = ""></input>
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Email</p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "changed_user_email" value = ""></input>
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Digite sua nova senha</p>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "changed_password"></input>
                        <p class = "my_data_text">Confirme sua nova senha</p>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width:54%;" name = "change_confirm_password"></input>
                        <button id ="btn_mydata_submit_incident" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmit(){
        alert("email inválido");
        var result =1;
        var checar = document.querySelector("#changed_user_email");
        var test = checar.value.indexOf("@");
        if (test == -1){
            alert("email inválido");
            result = 0;
            return false;
        }
        var checar = document.querySelector("#changed_password");
        var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;
        if(!checar.value.match(passw)){
            alert("password inválido");
            result =0;
            return false;
        }
        if (result == 0){
            return (false);
        }
        else{
            return (true);
        }
    }
    </script>`

Comment: i tried your code but still without solution i will try to reset my cache let's see.

Comment: i m using chrome i tried with firefox to, but still with the problem

Comment: Wow, finally working!! I changed the function name, and now it's working, well i don't know why it happened but is working now man !! kk